# How to get the item and count of that item from one sheet to another sheet in google-sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am very new to googlesheets and currently I am trying to plot the number and its count in google sheet.

So far I have tried this:

```
QUERY(DS!C2:C,"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 > 0 group by (Col1) order by count(Col1) desc", -1)
```

How to get the two columns: `Days` and `Count`.

I have shared the public google sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=517697699

The sheet to work on is `DS`.

**Required**

```
Days Count
1    something
2    something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the range in `{}` to use `Col1,Col2` notation:

`=QUERY({DS!C2:C},"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 > 0 group by (Col1) order by count(Col1) desc", -1)`